# for-loop time conversion using java

Tags: java

I'm just new in java.I am trying to convert money to time which is 1 dollar == 3 minutes but minutes-- wont let me display the exact minutes of time in the second loop

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    /*
    1 Dollar = 3 minutes
           */  


    //I am trying to convert money to time which is 1 dollar == 3 minutes but minutes-- 
    //wont let me display the exact minutes of time in the second loop
    int minutes;
    int amount;
    int hour=0;
    int time;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Amount");
    amount = in.nextInt();

        time = amount * 3;

        for (minutes = time; minutes>=59; minutes--)
        {
            minutes = minutes- 59;
            hour = hour+1;

            System.out.println(minutes+"minutes");
            System.out.println(hour+"hour");
         }    
    }
}
```

So if money == 40 here is the problem:

Please enter amount:

40

61 minutes

1 hour

here lies the problem it should be 2 minutes but because of minutes-- its not,

1 minutes

2 hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop is a weird way of implementing it you should replace `minute--` by `minute-=60` like so:

```
for (minutes = time; minutes>=60; minutes-=60) {
        hour = hour+1;
}
```

but you could just implement it by using arithmetic:

```
hour = minute/60;
minute = minute % 60;
```

Comment: sir what else could i use in afterthoughts besides minutes--,minutes++, minutes-=, minutes+=?

Comment: the list is long: ++, --, +=, -=, *=, %=, /=, |=, &=, ^=, <<=, >>=.. I might be missing some

Comment: thank you for helping me  sir i'll keep this in mind